# Extending 3D Plane to 4 Dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, extension-field, complex-geometry

I was thinking about a research topic, and I had was wondering- how might one extend the 3 dimensional plane to 4 dimensions? I know that for a 2 dimensional plane we can extend it to a 3 dimensional Riemann Sphere? 
Perhaps you could point me in the general direction? What would the name of such a object be? What is the general method of extending planes in such a way that, in the case of Riemann Sphere, positive infinity equals negative infinity?

Many thanks,

Amadeus

Comment: "I know that for a 2 dimensional plane we can extend it to a 3 dimensional Riemann Sphere?" Could you explain how?

Comment: I think the OP meant to use the term compactification, in which for example one can "add" the point infinity to the 2D complex plane by using the riemann sphere.

Comment: on topology side, there is the [one point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification). on geometry side, one can embed euclidean space into projective space using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). the geometry is known as [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry.  I know this is a bogus answer.  Perhaps, given one has a three dimensional plane (or perhaps we could call it a hyperplane), one interpretation is to regard this slice of time as being the static hyperplane we have drawn.  A common way I introduce a fourth dimension is to turn on time, so we have a dynamical system perhaps whose image is a hyperplane residing in (R^3)XR.  I realize this is banal, and can't blame you if you mark me down.